# Why is the whitespace still there in my ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, string

Ok so i have a user model in my rails application with a name method

```
def name
  "#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}"
end
```

The problem is that the first name might be like this

```
"Joshua               "
```

so

```
1.9.3-p125 :057 > u.name
 => "Joshua               Jones"
```

So i tried all the following

```
"#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}".squish
"#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}".gsub(/\s+/, " ").strip
"#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}".strip
"#{self.first_name.strip} #{self.last_name.strip}"
```

and still get this

```
1.9.3-p125 :057 > u.name
 => "Joshua               Jones"
```

Am i missing something on this

Comment: Do you mean you tried `def name; "#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}".squish; end` ?

Comment: I relized I had two name functions....my bad

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
"#{self.first_name.strip} #{self.last_name.strip}"
```

Not sure why the `.gsub` one didn't work for you.  It works for me and on [repl.it](http://repl.it/C6L) as well.

Comment: they all worked ...i just had two name functions in the user model...my bad